# Changing a user from being linked to a login to being without login

Tags: sql-server

I can create a user like this:

```
create user [foobar] for login [foobar];
```

I can also create a user like this:

```
create user [foobar] without login;
```

Is there a way to change a user that was created with the first method into a login-less user as though it had been created with the second method?

It seems that the opposite isn't possible (i.e. mapping a login-less user to a login) and it's not immediately clear to me why that would be the case. So if anyone can shed light on the reasons for that as well, I'd consider it a bonus.

Answer (score 2):

There is no method of directly altering a user to be loginless.  Having said, you could simply drop and recreate the login:

```
DROP USER foobar;
CREATE USER foobar
WITHOUT LOGIN;
```

Of course, you'd want to gather details about what rights the user has prior to dropping it, so you can recreate those permissions after the `CREATE USER` statement.

Attempting to connect a loginless user to a login, via the following syntax:

```
ALTER USER foobar
WITH LOGIN = foobar;
```

Does not work, contrary to what I reported here previously.  That attempt results in the following error:

> Msg 33016, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   The user cannot be remapped to a login. Remapping can only be done for users that were mapped to Windows or SQL logins.

Comment: I tried the syntax you suggest to link a loignless user to an existing login and got the ff error. `Msg 33016, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The user cannot be remapped to a login. Remapping can only be done for users that were mapped to Windows or SQL logins.
`. Did you try it and, if so and it worked for you, what version are you on? I'm on SQL 2012.

Comment: @BenThul - admittedly I didn't try it.  I've updated my answer.